# Programming an Arduino BT-V06 using an UNO using ICSP

Tags: programmer, icsp

I have an Arduino BT-V06 laying around which I can't program over bluetooth for some reason. To be honest I don't understand the exact problem, but the problem is described in the question https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/7843/arduino-bt-upload-problem.

To solve the problem of programming the board I'm trying to program the BT-V06 using an Arduino Uno. I wired it all up using the description at https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/installing-an-arduino-bootloader. The UNO seems fine, but the BT-V06 has the BATT-LOW led burning.

I've programmed the Arduino UNO using the Arduino ISP sketch. I've set the Arduino IDE to the COM port of the UNO, the target board to Arduino BT and the programmer to "Arduino as ISP". When trying to program the blink sketch I get the following error:

```
Sketch uses 1,030 bytes (3%) of program storage space. Maximum is 28,672 bytes.
Global variables use 9 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2,039 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2,048 bytes.
avrdude: verification error, first mismatch at byte 0x0002
         0x40 != 0x5c
avrdude: verification error; content mismatch
```

Could it be that the power requirements are too high to be powered through the UNO?

Comment: The sparkfun tutorial doesn't seems to mention the capacitor needed on the reset pin of the Arduino as ISP. `On the Arduino Uno, you'll need to connect a 10 uF capacitor between reset and ground` ([source](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP))

Comment: I'll have to buy the capacitor to try it out. Can you explain why it is needed?

Comment: When the IDE start to upload the code, it opens a serial connection. By design the Arduino Uno board resets when a new connection is opened. Because of this reset, the PC is communicating with the bootloader code, instead of the ISP sketch. [They suggest](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/DisablingAutoResetOnSerialConnection) you can also use a 120 ohm resistor between reset and 5v. Looking at the schematic, you can probably also directly connect it.